# Unsupported grant type error in RingCentral

Tags: oauth-2.0, ringcentral

I am calling the API to refresh my access token on RingCentral but it throws the following error

```
{
    "error":"invalid_request",
    "error_description":"Unsupported grant type",
    "errors":[
        {
            "errorCode":"OAU-250",
            "message":"Unsupported grant type"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Check and see if you are posting the `grant_type` form field and that it's set to `refresh_token`

Comment: Hello cliveza, I have posted grant_type with its value refresh_token. below is my calling method.

Comment: request.post({
     url: "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/oauth/token",
     form: {
         refresh_token: refreshToken,
         grant_type: "refresh_token",
         endpoint_id: endpointId
     },
     headers: {
         "Authorization": "Basic myToken",
         'Accept': 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
     }
 }, function(err, responce, responceData) {});

Comment: refres responceData  {
  "error" : "invalid_client",
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorCode" : "OAU-153",
    "message" : "Invalid client: ",
    "parameters" : [ {
      "parameterName" : "client_id",
      "parameterValue" : ""
    } ]
  } ],
  "error_description" : "Invalid client: "
}

Comment: The error indicates that your request is missing the client_id parameter.

What are the `Authentication Flows` listed for your application in the RingCentral Developer Portal? Is `Refresh Access Token` listed?

Are you following the documentation to implement refresh token flow:
https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefRefreshTokenFlow

Comment: Are you using Basic Auth to create the Authorization token that's passed in the headers? The username is the **Api Key** and the password is the **Api Secret**.

Comment: I am using Oauth 2. and passing refresh token while calling api for refresh token.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the RingCentral API available from [RingCentral GitHub](https://github.com/ringcentral)

Here is an example of an authentication request:

```
var request = new Request("/restapi/oauth/token",
new Dictionary<string, string> {
    { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
    { "redirect_uri", redirectUri },
    { "code", authCode },
    { "refresh_token_ttl", "604800" } });
```

Answer (score 0):

`grant_type=refresh_token` is supported by all the platform_type except *server/bot* platform type. Make sure you haven't created your apps with that platform type.

The parameter for refresh_token is almost same as grant_type password with minor change.

url will be same: https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/oauth/token

Headers:

```
"Accept":"application/json“
"Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded“
"Authorization",:"Basic <ClientID:ClientSecret in base 64>
```

Body:

In body, we need to pass the parameters in following way :

```
username=<account phone number>&password=<account password>&extension=<your extension>&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=<the refresh token generated>
```